# ipython notebook echo startup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have setup an ipython profile to look most of the libraries I use. I would like to see all these libraries I loaded without typing any command every time I create a new ipython notebook. If there any way I can echo startup.py into the newly created ipython notebook. Thanks,